# Twig if statement to false

Tags: twig

How do I set the following code to false?

```
{% if loop.first or breadcrumbs|length == loop.index or breadcrumbs|length - 1 == loop.index %}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Did you try adding some `(`and `)` to isolate some parts of your condition?

Comment: `{% if not(...) %}` would be the fastest solution here

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee!! That is the solution :)